# Project 2019 on-prem security mapping with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, project-server

I am building a script for automated deployment of SharePoint Farm with Project 2019 service application and a Project Web Application.
I used to manage Sharepoint online site collections several years ago and CSOM was the way, but I wonder if there was an alternative today?
At this point I am struggling with the post installation customisation. I have set the server up for Project Server security mode with
`Set-SPPRojectPermissionMode -Url $siteUrl -Mode ProjectServer`
Now how does one go about mapping an ActiveDirectory group (say `domain\project_admins`) to a Project Server group (`Administrators`)?